# Further examples of Principal Ideal Domain that are not Euclidean Domains

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, ideals

In several courses of algebra, I've heard that not all PIDs are EDs, and the canonical example is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ which I've heard over and over. Some cursory research both here and elsewhere has not turned up other examples of non-Euclidean principal ideal domains.

Where might I find resources describing them, or can anyone provide examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another nice example of a non-Euclidean PID is $ K[[x,y]][1/(x^2\!+\!y^3)]\,$ over a field $\,K,\,$ i.e. adjoin the inverse of $\,x^2\!+\!y^3$ to a bivariate power series ring over a field. The proof employs a general construction method, see

D. D. Anderson. [An existence theorem for non-euclidean PID’s,](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927878808823628)
Communications in Algebra, $16:6, 1221\!-\!1229, 1988$.

Also worth keeping in mind is that for number rings, a result of Weinberger (1973) (assuming GRH) implies that a UFD number ring R with infinitely many units is Euclidean. Therefore, e.g. real quadratic number rings are Euclidean $\!\iff\!$ PID $\!\iff\!$ UFD.

Comment: Nice example! Thank you. But I must ask -- what is GRH?

Comment: @walkar [Generalized Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis)

Comment: Just a further question: I was thinking about this, but didn't know if there was anything special about $x^2+y^3$. Will other polynomials work? Why does this one work?