# $R$ is PID iff $R$ is Euclidean Domain implies $R$ is a polynomial ring $K[x]$ for $K$ is field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is related to the following

[$R[x]$ is PID iff $R[x]$ is Euclidean domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530171/rx-is-pid-iff-rx-is-euclidean-domain?noredirect=1#comment9520599_4530171)

So converse is true but what about whether this condition implies $R$ being a polynomial ring?

I think there is no way I can approach this problem with my current knowledge, so if it is known or hinted or countered with an example I am all ear.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your question? If $R$ is a Euclidean domain, then it is also a PID. Are you asking for an example of a ring that is a Euclidean domain, but not isomorphic to a polynomial ring?

Comment: I am trying to ask that if PID implies ED then this ring is a polynomial ring.

Comment: Consider any field. That is both a PID and a euclidean domain, but it is not isomorphic to a polynomial ring.

Comment: Less trivial examples of rings that are Euclidean $\!\iff\!$ PID are UFD number rings with infinitely many units (e.g. real quadratic number rings) assuming GRH, as mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228908/242) that I cited in your linked prior question.

Comment: @Daianne'deSouza I recommend trying to prove that those rings Bill Dubuque mentioned are not isomorphic to a polynomial ring. It helps to note that $x\in R[x]$ (polynomial ring, i.e. $x$ is an indeterminate) is not root of any (nontrivial) polynomial with coefficients in $R$ (look at the degree). On the other hand, every element in the number rings is a root of some (nontrivial) polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.